# Can a C primitive be wider than a void*?

Tags: c, memory, void-pointers

I know that `void*` can hold any pointer but I wonder also if with casting it can hold anything besides an array or a struct, i.e., primitives and unions. Is this a guarantee with C (and if so which version) or just implementation-specific or not even a thing?

Comment: FYI, the C standard does not define “primitive” types, and it is not clear which subset of C types you mean by this. The *scalar* types are the arithmetic types (integers, enumerated types, “real floating” (floating point), and complex) and the pointer types. They do not include the `void` type. You might mean the scalar types, but you might also mean the non-derived types, which exclude arrays, structures, and unions, which are constructed from other types. The non-derived types also exclude function types and pointer types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder also if with casting it can hold anything besides an array or a struct, i.e., primitives and unions. Is this a guarantee with C [...]?

No, it is not.  As a counterexample, pointers are typically 32 bits wide in C implementations for 32-bit CPUs,<sup>*</sup> but C requires type `long long int` to be at least 64 bits wide.<sup>**</sup>  C places no upper bound on the size of any arithmetic type and no (explicit) lower bound on the size of any pointer type, so in principle, even `short` might be wider than `void *`.

---

<sup>*</sup>For example, [GCC uses the pointer representation specified by the target application binary interface (ABI)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Architecture-implementation.html#Architecture-implementation). On x86 Linux, that means the x86 System V ABI, which [defines the size of an address as 4 bytes](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.intro.html#data_representation).

<sup>**</sup> Per paragraph 5.2.4.2.1/1 of the current C language standard, the maximum value representable by an object of type `long long int` must be at least `9223372036854775807`, which is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.  If you include the sign bit, too, then it follows that a `long long int` requires at least 64 bits.

Comment: No, `char*` must have the same representation as `void*`.

Comment: Yes, @n.'pronouns'm., so?  I said `char` could be wider than `void *` (in principle).  That has nothing to do with `char *`.

Comment: could you add sources for your answer?

Comment: `char` cannot be wider than `void *`. Per C 2018 6.5.3.4 1, `sizeof (char)` is 1. Per 6.5.3.4 2, this is the size of the operand in bytes. Per 3.6 1, a “byte” is the addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment (hence not necessarily eight bits). `sizeof (void *)` cannot be less than 1, so it cannot be narrower than a `char`.

Comment: You are right, @EricPostpischil.  `char` might, in principle, be the same size as `void *`, but not larger.  I have changed the claim in this answer to say instead that `short` might be larger.

Comment: @theEpsilon, what details do you want to have sourced?  The authoritative source for a "C does not specify [...]" claim is the whole C language specification, but I can be more specific about positive details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger just the counterexample with the 32 bit pointer and 64 bit long long. If you could even find something for "C places no upper bound on the size of any arithmetic type and no (explicit) lower bound on the size of any pointer type" that would be awesome too ;)

Comment: @theEpsilon: C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 specifies rules for bounds on the integer types, and paragraph 1 says, of these bounds, “Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.” Thus, the standard is here not placing any restriction on how large the representable values in integer types may be.

Comment: @theEpsilon: No bounds existing on the floating types, since they are permitted to represent infinities. Further, no bound is placed on their finite ranges, as C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 12 as similar wording: “The values given in the following list shall be replaced by constant expressions with implementation-defined values that are greater or equal in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign”.

Comment: @theEpsilon: There are implicit lower bounds on pointer widths. Pointers must be able to distinguish different objects, and an implementation must be able to support 4095 characters in a string literal, each byte of which must have an address, so a pointer must have at least 12 bits, so it must be wider than a `char` in any implementation where `char` is eight bits. Hosted environments must support an object of 65,535 bytes, so a pointer must be at least 16 bits in them.

Comment: @eric: it's true that `sizeof(void*)>=sizeof(char)`. However, there is no guarantee that all of the bits in a `void*` be usable. Consequently, I think it is possible in some implementation of fantasy for the cast from `char` to `void*` and back to `char` to drop some bits.

Comment: @theEpsilon, I have added citations to authoritative sources supporting the assertions that pointers on 32-bit platforms are typically 32 bits, and that `long long int` is always at least 64 bits on conforming C implementations.